# Facebook connect restarts my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm building an iPhone App where i want to add Facebook login.
In viewDidLoad i've added:

```
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"MYAPPID" andDelegate:self];
    facebook.sessionDelegate=self;
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
```

When the user taps a button i invoke a function that does:

```
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];
    [facebook authorize:permissions ];
```

It launches safari and makes the facebook login; the problem is that when it returns to the app, it relaunches the app, while i need to return directly to my ViewController, not to the FirstViewController. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting .... whywhywhy? Was it "not constructive" as usual?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in an old SO thread

In facebook.m :

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions {
    self.permissions = permissions;

    [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
}
```